# Private storage folder to store paid app specific content in Android?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that would have an In-app purchase and download Videos from my server and store them on the device. 
The problem is, the Videos are paid videos and are to be maintained in a highly secure place **inside the app itself.**

What are the possibilities of doing it? I had a look at setting `android:exported="false"`, but it just restricts other apps to access my app's data. But how do I store the videos in a place which are restricted to be viewed by default even when connecting the device to a PC?

Are the apps allowed to store data in the device's `\data` folder? If so, please tell me how!

Answer (score 0):

You can store files in your app's data folder, and as long as the phone isn't rooted, only your app should be able to access them.

However.  The local storage on phones is generally limited, so storing videos there is a bad idea.  Also, unless you're integrating your own video player, you might have issues trying to get the phone to play videos in your private folder.

To speak to the security issue, I'd suggest trying to keep them on the sd card, and experiment with either encrypting them, so they can't be read raw from disk, or (possibly) experimenting with file permissions, although I doubt the latter would work.

To do the encryption, I'd download the video, encrypt it and save it to the sd card.  When you want to watch, decrypt and temporarily save to local storage for viewing.  Not sure what kind of performance that will get, though.  Plus, if you're relying on the OS to play your videos, you could have the same permission issues mentioned above.  Depending on how critical this all is, you could explore something where the file/folder structure is obscured, so getting at them manually is more complex.  Won't prevent all grab attempts, but will deter casual users.

Comment: You would have to download an encrypted version, and then decrypt it on the fly as you play it. Otherwise the work around to get a copy of the video is trivial.

Comment: This looks really tough! I have implemented the VideoPlayer using VideoView and MediaPlayer classes in my app. How about storing it in the Device memory instead of SDCard? Advisable? And also are there any other sample code that does this job? Please let me know!